# No Ubuntu partitions on installed dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 and dual booting. Ubuntu has 10GB of space and I'm running out of space. I want to increase this to 100GB, so I went to the Windows disk manager, it shows 100MB FAT16, 14GB recovery NTFS, 540GB OS NTFS. There are no partitions shown for Ubuntu/Linux in either the Windows disk manager or gparted. I used Windows disk manager to free up 100GB of space on my hard drive, is there a way to transfer my installed Ubuntu onto the new partition? Apparently, my existing install must be on Wubi, though I don't recall installing it there.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to transfer my installed Ubuntu onto the new partition?

Yes: ([MigrateWubi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi)) but I would not rely too much on it.

I'd recommend to first backup your documents, then partition your disk ([this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) can help), then try the above script. 
If the script fails, or if you want to install Ubuntu in a clean way, then use an Ubuntu install disk for a [standard install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks a million! I see they also give a link on how to manually migrate, this is great, thanks again.

Comment: I used the MigrateWubi, it worked perfectly! Thanks all for the suggestions. :-)